# Visual Studio Team Services Change Theme

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Team Services, and I was wondering, in the code editor, can I change the theme, because white kills my eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update: Dark theme is now available out of the box.

See also:

- https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1057010882989998083.html

---

There is no way to currently do this from the web UI itself. But there are options.

- [UserStyles: VSTS - Dark](https://userstyles.org/styles/134244/vsts-dark) 
  [image]
- [UserStyles: Dark Visual Studio Website](https://userstyles.org/styles/136568/dark-visual-studio-website-vsts-style)
  [image]

It works through a UserStyles script plugin in Chrome. I'm not sure how well these will work with VSTS extensions, but it works rather well with the default experience.

This Chrome extension may also serve as an eyeshade:

- [DarkReader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en)

There are a number of User Voice items on which you can vote to make this a priority to build it into the product. The one below seems to have the most votes. I suggest you add yours to it.

- [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31062022-dark-theme-for-vsts-and-tfs-web-portal).

Answer (score 4):

With Sprint 142 Update, you'll be able to use a Dark Theme. See details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sprint-142-update#dark-theme

Comment: Awesome!! But: Any news on how to adapt extensions to the new themes?

Comment: We are working on passing theme info to extensions and notifying extensions when the theme changes. It will be available very soon. I'll update here once the doc about this is ready.